# Allow dynamic choice in Django ChoiceField

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) in my application for creating tags-like select dropdowns. Users can select number of predefined tags or create a new tag.

Relevant forms class part:

```
   all_tags = Tag.objects.values_list('id', 'word')

   # Tags
    tags = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=all_tags,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'question-tags',
                'multiple': 'multiple',
            }
        )
    )
```

The problem is that `Django` **won't allow custom tags(choices)** upon validation. There error I'm getting looks like this: `Select a valid choice. banana is not one of the available choices.`

Is there any way around it?

Thanks

Comment: send an ajax request on tag creation (before submit) to save the new tag?

Comment: Are you using `django-select2` (or one of the many Django applications for working with Select2) at all?

Comment: @skndstry not sure if that is the best way

Comment: @KevinBrown I'm using plaing select2 with django. It's working great, the only problem is the validation one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the choicefield to charfield, and use the clean method to filter unwanted choices depending on certain conditions. Simply changing it to a char field with a select widget would work since Select2 is javascript anyways.

```
class Myform(forms.Form):
    tags = forms.CharField(
    max_length=254,
    widget=forms.Select(
        choices=tags,  # here we set choices as part of the select widget
        attrs={
            'class': 'question-tags',
            'multiple': 'multiple',
            }
        )
    )
    def clean_tags(self):
        tags = self.cleaned_data['tags']
        # more tag cleaning logic here
        return tags
```