# Django Forms with Choice Field : Allow user to provide their own answers

Tags: django, django-forms, choicefield

I am new to Django and tried looking at documentation and a few posts on this forum, but I haven't been able to resolve my problem yet. I'd appreciate any pointers/examples and thanks for your time and help.

I have a working setup for a form with `ChoiceField` that has 4 choices (`CharField`). I am trying to include a 5th open option so the User could type their own response. I tried including code for widget, but that made a text box appear below the drop down list. Even with the widget, the validation fails (unless one of the 4 choices is selected) and I have not been able to resolve this problem either.

Is there a solution so the form could accept User inputs within the `ChoiceField` drop down list?

Best,
Aya

Comment: You should post your code if you want to get any help.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't posted any code, or error message, so I am guessing a bit.

Make sure your form has required=False for the Choice widget. If that is set to True, it will fail the validation.

Answer (score -1):

check out [Allow dynamic choice in Django ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29526511/allow-dynamic-choice-in-django-choicefield)

Optional values will result in an error if you call:

```
if form.is_valid():
```